# How can I host multiple websites in IIS 7 and use the same MVC application for all them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

How can I host multiple websites in IIS 7 and use the same MVC application for all them such that each website:

1. Has it's own root directory so user's can upload their own files (html, css, javascript) without seeing other websites'content
2. Uses the same MVC application - so updates to the application affect all sites
3. Users cannot affect the MVC application in any way (preferably it will be hidden from them)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a directory where you deploy the MVC files, named "AppFoo". Note that the configuration file `web.config` will be shared between all of the sites, you'll have to load per-site configuration at on-demand runtime by looking at the `Host` HTTP header or other binding information.
2. Create each website in IIS and get it to use the the application directory you created. Ideally each website runs under its own application pool with its own user-account, all of the user-accounts will have access to AppFoo directory.
3. Create a new directory somewhere, e.g. under `C:\Inetpub\sites\` named `WebsiteA`, `WebsiteB`, etc. Each folder re-sets the NTFS permission ACLs that only allows each website's application pool user access. Inside these create folders called "Content", "Views" and "Logs"
4. For each website in IIS (I assume you're using the root) set up a Virtual Directory called "Content" and "Views" (which is how I assume you have set-up your MVC applications), map these to subdirectories of the folders you created in Step 3.
5. For each website, go to the Logging page and set the log-path to the `Logs` directory you created for the site in step 3.

Note that this plan is based on the assumption that MVC evaluates IIS virtual directories in its VirtualPathProvider. If not then you'll have to roll your own VirtualPathProvider to load per-website content, again, on a per-hostname basis.

Comment: Thanks Dai! For point 2, how do I set each site to use the application directory?

Comment: It's under "Basic Settings" on a website node in the tree view.

Comment: Do you mean point the root of the website to the MVC app folder or add an application to the root?

Comment: The first. So all of the websites share the same filesystem directory (at least for the application files), the user-editable directories are virtual and mapped to their own folders. Note that users will not have the ability to edit the root directory of the website, so custom google verification pages won't work unless, instead, you have the application in a virtual sub-directory.

Comment: Thanks Dai - I have tried what you suggested and it does work except for the root directory limitation. I have tried this second approach where the application is referenced by a virtual directory but this produces a global.asax error which I cannot seem to resolve. Can you take a look at this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961052/getting-a-global-asax-file-error-when-using-virtual-directories-for-an-mvc-appli. Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up giving each user their own site in IIS and then added an application to each which mapped to the MVC app. This wasn't quite what I was hoping for, but we can make it work for our purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running one code base, then setup one site that uses [domain routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx) or a global filter to capture the domain, save it and use it as a key for folders, etc...

```
public class DomainFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private SiteDomainRepository _siteDomainRepository = new SiteDomainRepository();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
        var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal ? "www.testdomain.com" : HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
        var domain = hostSplit[1];

        var siteDomain = _siteDomainRepository.GetByRowKey(domain);

        viewBag.DomainName = host.ToLower();
        viewBag.Domain = siteDomain.RowKey;
        viewBag.Class = siteDomain.Key;
        viewBag.TrackingCode = siteDomain.TrackingCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how does this allow me to offer a separate root directory for each website?

Comment: you don't need a separate root directory - essentially, each domain would have a folder in the root with no access above that - controlled by your app.

Comment: I want a separate root directory so that users can upload their own google verification pages, or favicons or other files.