# Getting a global.asax file error when using virtual directories for an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have a working MVC 4 application deployed to an IIS server. I wanted to duplicate this MVC app inside of another website in IIS so I linked the Bin, Views, Scripts, and Images of the working MVC site to the new site using virtual directories. I then copied the global.asax and web.config files to the root directory of the new site. When reviewing the new site's content view, it looks identical to the original's site directory layout, except that folders are virtual.

When I go to run the new site in a browser, I get the following error:

```
Parse Error: Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PrApp.MvcApplication'.
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="PrApp.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

I've read up on this, but could not find anything on point. Most dealt with bad assemblies or missing namespaces but since I know the assemblies work I am not sure why I would be receiving this error. My assumption is that this website would function exactly like the other since the files and dll's are all "present" but perhaps this is a bad assumption due to my lack of experience with complied code.

My goal is to run the same mvc app within multiple IIS sites so they each can have their own root directory while I can maintain a single code base.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
Image of IIS. - Highlighted site is the one with the virtual directories. The other expanded site is the working MVC app.

[image]

UPDATE 2:
I removed the global.asax file from the root of the secondary site and the error went away. NOw I am getting the following error: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. I have also tried converting my virtual directories to applications but to no avail. I'm not sure if this is progress. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Did you convert your virtual directories to applications?  Could you maybe show your IIS site structure?

Comment: Thanks! I did not make them apps - I have added the image as requested.

Comment: So, taking your mvc2 site as an example, that isn't a sub-site of some other IIS site from the looks of it.  It is its own site.  There's no need to make the directories like bin and images virtual directories in that case.  Just point it to the location on disk.

Comment: Yes but then each site does not get it's own root. It becomes a shared root which makes uploading one's own files, google verification files, facvicons, etc impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of architecture you need, but, my first thought from your last comment would be to have one application and then create directories for each user as needed in a shared location.  It seems like overkill to create a new application for each user just to store some files.

Comment: Thanks.I ended up creating a separate site for each user in IIS and then created an application in each that points to the MVC app. This wasn't quite the solution I was hoping for, but we will make it work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Well as nothing seemed to offer exactly what we wanted, we ended up building out real directory structures for our hosted sites and then created html pages in each that communicated with the app via webAPI and/or iFrames depending on what is required.

The only other thing I could think of was to somehow maintain the same code base across thousands of sites programmatically. If anyone has any other ideas, I'm all ears!