# Dynamically Set Web.Config at Application Start for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application built in ASP.NET MVC that will be used by several clients.  Each client has its own database to store information, but each instance will have the same functionality.  I am using tips from this question/answer [How can I host multiple websites in IIS 7 and use the same MVC application for all them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15939632/2874556) to consolidate to a single app folder for easier maintenance.

Right now, I setup each client in its own folder and each with its own Web.Config file.  There are a couple of appConfig settings as well as the connectionStrings that are unique to that client.

What I would like to do is have a single app folder that contains the MVC project, but the application then dynamically pulls the correct web.config folder (stored in another folder.)  I will select the web.config probably based on the host settings (i.e. www.domain.com loads the domain.web.config file.)

I would like for this to update the behavior of the ConfigurationManagement object.  I have seen several posts on how to load a configuration file (and most are regarding app.config for desktop apps) but not how to make it a semi-global change or unique characteristics of ASP.NET MVC and web.config.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is called multi-tenancy. And this is quite complex task.

You can't really play about with `web.config` substitution and for one request give one file and for another request give another config. What if 2 requests from different tenants will come exactly at the same time?

At the moment we are converting our application to multi-tenancy and this is very complex task, so can't really be described in one answer on SO.

You can have a look on this write-up http://www.scribd.com/doc/140181293/setting-up-an-mvc4-multi-tenant-site-v1-1
Also if you google for "multi-tenancy MVC" you'll get many articles on that.

Basic principles for our multi-tenancy look like this: DI container is aware of different tenants and knows that request for `tenant1.site.com` should use configuration set 1 and for request `tenant2.site.com` configuration set 2 should be used. 
Apart from DI container, no other component knows about tenants. And DI container orchestrates the configurations. Connection strings are sitting in configuration objects and these objects are given to EF contexts before they are created... somewhat complex.

If your case is simple and you don't use caches, to substitute the connection strings, I'd save them outwith `web.config` and provide them based on tenant request. Probably you can get away without complex DI setups.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of maintaining multiple config files is small if you use external config files to isolate the connection strings that are unique to the customer leaving the bulk of the config file unchanged.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
</configuration>
```

For more options about resolving config information at runtime look at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

For app settings in an internal file see [Moving Settings to another config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821735/moving-settings-to-another-config-file)